# How can I make multiple Toolbars in Eyeshot 12?

Tags: vb.net, eyeshot

I would like to make a second vertical Toolbar.

I tried with this code but I can see any result.

```
Dim buttons2 As ToolBarButton() = New ToolBarButton(1) {}
Dim bmp1 As Bitmap = My.Resources.Bitmap1
buttons2(0) = New devDept.Eyeshot.ToolBarButton(bmp1, "Something", "Something", devDept.Eyeshot.ToolBarButton.styleType.PushButton, True)

Dim bmp2 As Bitmap = My.Resources.Bitmap2
buttons2(1) = New devDept.Eyeshot.ToolBarButton(bmp2, "Something more", "Something more", devDept.Eyeshot.ToolBarButton.styleType.PushButton, True)

Dim tb As ToolBar = New ToolBar(ToolBar.positionType.VerticalMiddleLeft, True, buttons2)
```

Comment: How are you adding the toolbar to the `ViewportLayout` ? And have you tried adding the toolbar in the control in design mode and use visibility instead ? Personally i have many toolbars and i just created empty toolbars that i fill dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a new ToolBar in Eyeshot **not** in design mode:

- create a new `ToolBar` as you did
- add this new `ToolBar` to the `Environment.OsservableCollection < ToolBar >`
- call the method `Environment.CompileUserInterfaceElements()`

Snippet code in C# WPF:

```
ToolBarButton toolBarButton = new ToolBarButton(buttonImage, "spongeBob", "spongeBob", ToolBarButton.styleType.PushButton, true);

ObservableCollection<ToolBarButton> toolBarButtons = new ObservableCollection<ToolBarButton>() { toolBarButton };

ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar(ToolBar.positionType.VerticalMiddleLeft, true, toolBarButtons);
model1.GetToolBars().Add(toolBar);
model1.CompileUserInterfaceElements();
```

[Multiple ToolBars picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNn6E.png)